# Adding a help window to an application - C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've already searched on SO to see if there has been a similar question but I haven't found anything so far.

I'm looking to add a help window to my application, similar to the ones found in many other applications (Example below):

[image: HTC Sync]

As you can see the help window allows you to give plenty of instructions for particular functions of an application, as well as the ability to print it off for future reference.

How would I go about adding this to my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The screenshot you posted is based on [Windows Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb267846.aspx).  There is an [SDK available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms670169(VS.85).aspx) from Microsoft to generate this.

In addition, there are many commercial products that dramatically simplify help creation, such as [Adobe's Robohelp](http://www.adobe.com/products/robohelp/).

Comment: Looking at some of the help files available they appear to be created and hooked up using C, how would this work with a C# application?

Comment: @Jamie Keeling: You setup a HelpProvider, then call SetHelpNavigator for specific controls.  If you do that, hitting F1 will open the appropriate part of your help file.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpprovider.sethelpnavigator.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can also look for a CHM editors / builders.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [HelpProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpprovider.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [MDI Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984329(VS.71).aspx).  Printing, menu bars, etc, are done the same as any basic winforms application.

Comment: He asked how to provide help to users, MDI is not related.